# Python - Scapy and nfqueue change outgoing GET request, set_payload not effecting payload

Tags: python, linux, http, scapy, netfilter

I'm new to nfqueue and am trying to change a packet's payload using it.

however, when I poll the payload from the 'set-ed' packet(simply named 'packet' in the following snippet), i get the original payload of the packet before the change.
even-though when i read `scapkt[TCP].payload` it has the right payload.
where did i go wrong? (change_image is the callback)

```
def change_image(packet):

    scapkt = IP(packet.get_payload())

    #is a TCP packet
    if scapkt.proto == 6:

        data = str(scapkt[TCP].payload)

        getImage = re.search('GET [a-zA-Z0-9/]{1,}\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG) HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: [a-zA-Z0-9\.]{1,}', data)
        if getImage != None:

            original_len = len(scapkt[TCP].payload)

            data = data.replace(getImage.group(), 'GET ' + image + ' HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ' + host)

            scapkt[TCP].payload = data

            postMod_len = len(scapkt[TCP].payload)
            scapkt[IP].len = original_len + (postMod_len - original_len)

            del scapkt[IP].chksum
            del scapkt[TCP].chksum

            packet.set_payload(str(scapkt))

            print packet.get_payload()

    packet.accept()
```

I am using the NetfilterQueue fork by the awesome [fqrouter](https://github.com/fqrouter/python-netfilterqueue)

FYI: i know this code might not work as intended, but I'm learning to work with nfqueue and am trying to write a simple PoC

Comment: I am doing something similar and seeing the original payload as well, did you ever get it working?